# Testing VPN from same network I want to VPN into

Tags: vpn, troubleshooting, juniper, srx

This is a general question. I'm building a VPN for my work network on a Juniper SRX firewall, and I need to troubleshoot it.

Right now, I have to walk to a cafe or library to test it and then go back into my office to change the configuration. This is very inefficient. In addition, I can't use any of the VPN session monitoring tools on my firewall since I'm never in the office while I am testing VPN.

My VPN policy is Untrust-to-Trust only. If I set up a Trust-to-Trust policy for it, will that introduce (or take way) variables I need to pay attention to in the troubleshooting process?

Is there a convenient and secure way to test VPN from an Untrusted network while I am on my work network? (e.g. use a proxy server or a commercial VPN like Private Internet Access)?

Do you have any recommendations on how to best do this?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: TeamViewer, LogMeIn, GoToAssist, etc., etc. on your home computer. Use that to connect to and test your VPN.

Comment: Been there... such a pain! I used to walk across the tree to a bar! At one job they had an extra DSL line, that helped. I also dialled out on the fax line before! Just gotta be creative :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a smart phone as a WIFI access point... connect a laptop to it to do all your testing while sitting right at your desk in your office.

Comment: This was the most convenient solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

I often do the same thing, and to accomplish it, I have my home computer (and home firewall) set up to accept RDP connections.  So I can just RDP to my home computer, and then test the VPN connection to work from there.